# Trouble receiving datagram packets in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, udp

I am currently attempting to recieve datagram packets through UDP. The code I am using is in Java (for Android). What I have already done is created an interface to where the user will click a button "Start". From there the start button will initiate receiving the datagram packets. Below I have began the code, but Im not sure what Im doing wrong? I wnt the data to display to an Edit Text. Do I have to create an intent to begin the activity??

any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


public void onClick (View v){
    txtData = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtData);
    //Log.v("EditText", txtData.getText().toString());

    try {
        final int PORT = 50009;
        DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket (PORT);
        byte[] buffer = new byte [1024]; 

        //loop forever, waiting to receive packets and printing them
        while(true){
            dsocket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket (buffer, buffer.length);
            //wait to receive a datagram
            dsocket.receive(packet);


            //converts the contents to a string and displays them
            //String msg = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());  


            //Reset the length of the packet before reusing it.
            packet.setLength(buffer.length);
            buffer =packet.getData();

            dsocket.close();
        }}
    catch (SocketException e){
        Log.v("SocketExceptionOccurred", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.v("IOExceptionOcurred", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... you haven't given us any kind of error message to work with.  Still, I can definitely see two things that are wrong:

1. That `while (true)` loop is going to hang the UI thread.  You can't do that
2. You are attempting to do network operations from the UI thread.  You can't do that either

Look into the Service class.  You probably want to do your networking in an IntentService.